# How to call custom event in VBscript

Tags: html, dom, vbscript

I have an C++ application which will take care of script execution. currently i want to execute custom event firing in Vb script and J script. I written code for J Script and working fine, how can i achieve this in Vb Script. (mainly targeting IE)

```
function customEventFn()
{
 alert("sample");
}
var element = document.getElementById("elemneid");
customEventFn.call(element);
```

Please help me to solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last i found answer to my problem. The above methods does not work in Internet Explorer before version 9. use attachEvent method to register an event handler in earlier Internet Explorer versions. but it wont fire custom event.
you need to install IE9 for correct working of the script.

1. Add Following tag to the HEAD of the htm file.
   -meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" -
2. write event body wrapped with function
3. get reference to an element by using getElementById’
4. Create custom event and attach that event to the element with call back as function defined in step1.
5. fire custom event
6. remove custom event from listener(removeEventListener).

   Function CustomFunction()

   'function body

   End Function

   set customFn = getRef("CustomFunction")

   set element = document.getElementById("elemid");

   element.addEventListener "OnSampleEvent", customFn

   set Event = document.createEvent("sampleEvent")

   Event.initCustomEvent "OnSampleEvent", false, false, nil

   element.dispatchEvent(Event)

   element.removeEventListener "OnSampleEvent", customFn